# Partial Keyword Searching (MS SQL 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Current, I've got a stored procedure that has a main goal of doing a full text search through a database table of films and tv shows.  In order to get it to do partial-keyword searching, I added some code in SQL to split up the search query by spaces, and output a statement like the following:

`"batman*" ~ "be*"`

The original string, "batman be", for instance, could be generated from a textbox on the page as the user is typing and on each javascript keyup event, I send whatever is in that textbox to the stored proc for results to get results as I type (like autocomplete).  In this case, the user may have been looking for "Batman Begins", or "The Batman: Batgirl Begins" (a TV show episode) and they both should show up as a result.

Below is a sample of my query. @partialKeywordString is, in the example above, `"batman*" ~ "be*"`.

```
SELECT f.title
FROM Films f INNER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(Films, Title, @partialKeywordString) f_key ON f.filmid = f_key.[key]
ORDER BY f_key.Rank DESC
```

The problem I have with the query is that the ranking doesn't seem to be exactly what I'd expect.  If I were to just search for "batman", one would believe that all movie titles, beginning with, or only containing the word "batman" would appear first. But they don't.
A sample result of what happens when one searches for just "batman" is below:

"Batman: The animated series - Episode 114"
"Adventures of Batman and Robin - Episode 218"
"Batman and Robin - Episode 101"
"The Batman - Episode 101"
"Batman and Robin - Episode 204"

Much further down the list is the movie I was searching for--"Batman Begins" or even just "Batman".

I'm looking for advice on how to tweak this query--I'm definitely not a SQL expert, and I feel like I just man-handled the above code to get it to work.  I have a feeling there's a more elegant or powerful solution, and I just haven't found it yet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more researching, I'm going to try and use Lucene.Net for my movie-title search engine, and not rely on Full-Text Searching in SQL Server 2005.  Early testing shows that the results have been better and more relevant with Lucene. A search for "batman" returns the following partial result-set:

- Batman
- Batman Begins
- Batman Returns
- Batman and Robin: Batman Takes Over
- Batman Beyond: A Touch of Curaré
- Batman Beyond: Babel
- The Batman: Season 02
- The Batman: Topsy Turvy
- Batman and Robin: Tunnel of Terror
- Batman Beyond [Animated TV Series]
- The New Adventures of Batman: Curses! Oiled Again!
- The New Adventures of Batman: This Looks Like a Job for Bat-Mite!

Answer (score 0):

I think you find SQL Server Full Text works just as good but you have to understand how to build the keywords. It is not the same as Lucene, especially in terms of indexing. I think you will find that SQL Server would be better , in terms of scalability and features - especially SQL 2008 now it is part of the engine.

Comment: You may be right about SQL 2008, as I have not used it, but, so far, Lucene has given me much better results and flexibility, in far less time.